# Click event didn't attach to button

Tags: javascript

I need to attach a click event on a `button` tag. I've tried addEventLister, but it still doesn't work.

```
widget.innerHTML = "<button id=\"w_btn\">do action</button>";

w_btn = document.getElementById("w_btn");

w_btn.addEventListener("click", 
    function() {
        alert("sdf");
    }
);
```

Comment: Are you used to ActionScript? Because I dont think addEventListener works in JS.

Comment: @Fredy31 that is **not** true.

Comment: This appears to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/yf9kM/
Is there some other code you forgot to include in your question? Where does `widget` get defined?

Comment: @Neal depends on the browser AFAIK - it's in IE9 but not earlier.

Comment: @Neal, Sorry, I'm fresh out of school and never saw addEventListener used in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third optional is [**required**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) in some browsers.
The following code should work in every decent browser  (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hnPP/2/):

```
var widget = document.getElementById("widget");
widget.innerHTML = "<button id=\"w_btn\">do action</button>";
var w_btn = document.getElementById("w_btn"); //Added var
w_btn.addEventListener("click",
    function() {alert("test")},
    false
);
```

Another possible cause is the existence of another element with ID `w_btn`, which appears before the `#widget` element. To solver this, you can adjust your code. Since you overwrite the contents of the `#widget` element, the first and only content is the button. Define:

```
var w_btn = widget.firstChild;
```

A last possibility is that you're in strict mode. In strict mode, using undeclared variables is **forbidden**.

Comment: I've got this working on FF, Chrome and IE9 without the 3rd optional parameter...

Comment: @ThiagoSantos Older versions of FF requires the third parameter. I have listened some possible causes of the problem. The last option seems likely.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. I made a jsFiddle for you, here: http://jsfiddle.net/5hnPP/1/. Using a "real" button works. You may be running into a DOM issue. Let you know if I find anything more useful.

EDIT: Hmm, even adding the button dynamically works for me. Are you naming your element correctly? (Notice the updated jsFiddle link - has updated markup).